# Exclude members in a smart group

Tags: civicontribute, smartgroups

I want to create a group of members that have paid their contribution last year, but not yet this year, and do not have an email address.

With an email address, the solution is simple: create two groups "paid last year" and "paid this year". Send an email via CiviMail to "last year" by excluding "this year". CiviMail only takes into account the contacts with email.

But how to do so with the ones without email? I do not see a way to "subtract" (= excluding members who paid this year) two groups outside CiviMail.

Or do I need to activate CiviMember for this purpose? Now, I enter the value of the year of payment into the field "Source of contribution" and, for the moment, we do not see the added value of another component CiviMember.

Answer (score 6):

There's two answers, although you probably just need the first:

- Instead of Advanced Search, use Search Builder (also in the Search menu).  Use "paid this year" and "email address is empty".
- Alternatively, there's a custom search (**Search menu > Custom Searches**) called **Include/Exclude by Group/Tag**.  So alternatively you can create a smart group in Search Builder "No email" and combine it with existing searches using the include/exclude search.